# No module named 'gym'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

После установки gym с помощью pip

```
pip install gym
```

Далее ввожу в jupyter notebook

```
import gym
```

Выводится следующая ошибка

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
```

Comment: `pip list` что показывает?

Comment: У вас команда `pip` может указывать на версию python,  отличную от той, с которой вы работаете в jupyter notebook (установили в pyhton3, а работаете со python2, или наоборот)

Comment: в pip list есть gym

Answer (score 2):

Выбрать в меню Anaconda Prompt

```
conda install gym
```

Или прямо в ячейке notebook

```
! pip install gym
```